# Asp.Net How to control, does an element exist in document?

Tags: asp.net

I want to control does an element exist in document with its ID in Asp.Net project when page's first or postback loading.

Thansk for your helps already now.

Comment: Hi kerberos, what is you original language ? 
What do you mean if it exist - you mean if it's visible ?

Comment: as I understand:
He wants to know If a control with a specific ID is already in the document... there might be some situations where you add controls dynamically.. 

just my guess :)

Comment: My orginal language is Turkish. Sorry for my bad english. I tray to explain clearly. i use validate methods for my asp.net form with javascript. sametime in same page when user click a asp.net checkbox, a part of page is visible. i make this visible job in asp.net code behind. so if i use js's validate parameters before postback for unvisible element, i get javascript error. Because that element is'nt exist. so i want to control form element with it's asp.net ID every case before validate codes runs. if i can control elements' exist i think solve this issue. i hope explain was clearly :)

Comment: Why don't you use an asp.net validator?

Comment: Paco, there is no valid reason, it's just my habit :) i will consider your suggest. thank all of you for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your hiding a section of your page on postback, i'm assuming via the controls Visible property. The problem with this approach is that the control is never rendered when Visible="False", this is probably why your javascript code throws an error.

You can use the css property Display and set its value to None, this will allow the element to render but not display. I'm not sure what your using for a container, so i'm using a panel in my example (which renders as a div).

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlContainer" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

Then instead of toggling the Visible property, you can hide the panel using the CSS display property.

```
pnlContainer.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Comment: Yes you understood correct. Sorry for my bad english again. I wanted to do as you said. Thank you very much.